# How to put array on WritableMap object in ReactNative bridge

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-bridge, react-native-ui-components

To communicate with Android to ReactNative I use `RCTEventEmitter`. Using this I need parse array to RN side and this array should set on `WritableMap` object.
On `WritableMap` object can put Array as shown below,

```
void putArray(@NonNull String key, @Nullable ReadableArray value);
```

How to create and add data into `ReadableArray` ?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the WritableArray.
You can create one like this:

```
// Initialize an empty array
WritableArray array = new WritableNativeArray();

// Add items to array using its push methods, for example
array.pushString("test");
```

Comment: It's requiring a ReadableArray, and can we cast WritableArray to ReadableArray?

Comment: The WritableArray  extends ReadableNativeArray that implements ReadableArray. You should be able to use this structure without any issues. Also I forgot to give you an example of how to use the WritableArray. You just need to use the push methods like this: ``` array.pushString("test");```

Answer (score 1):

`Arguments` from React Native Bridge has a helper method [`Arguments.fromList(list)`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/Arguments.java#L251) that returns a `WritableArray`, which is a subclass of `ReadableArray`, so satisfies the condition and is ready to pass to `putArray`.

---

For example, to take a list and push it to a JS event as an array property:

**Kotlin**:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments
// ...

val params = Arguments.createMap().apply {
   putArray("data", Arguments.fromList(someList))
   // ...put more params
}
```

**Java**:

```java
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
// ...

WriteableArray array = Arguments.fromList(someList);
WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
params.putArray(array);
// ...put more params
```

Pass these to `.emit("SomeEvent", params)` and JS should receive `{ data: [...someList] }`.

---

There's also [`Arguments.makeNativeArray(list)`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/Arguments.java#L51), which has an almost identical API and implementation to `.fromList` - both create a `WritableArray` by iterating a list arg, pushing each item by type. The only differences I can see are:

- `.fromList` explicitly handles nested arrays
- `.makeNativeArray` explicitly handles `null` (returning an empty array)